# How to calculate \$R_{\text{in}}\$ in this circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, resistance, inverting-amplifier

I know for an ideal inverting op-amp, the equation for finding gain would be \$\frac{-R_1}{R_{\text{in}}}\$, but how can I find \$R_{\text{in}}\$ in this circuit?

[image: **enter image description here**]

Comment: Use Thevenin/Norton.

Comment: Which resistor is \$R_{in}\$ and which is \$R_2\$? All I see is \$R, R_1 , R_L\$.

Comment: There is no resistor R2 in your circuit. Moreover, it is not a good approach to use existent formulas without knowing how they are derived,,,,why not calculate by yourself?

Comment: -R1/Rin in this case, typo there

Comment: You can edit your question whenever you like to make it make sense.

Comment: What is the current through the resistor marked 2R, assuming the op-amp is in balance?

Comment: There is no current given. It is supposed to solve the ratio of resistors to get the gain.

Comment: The question is too vague. What are the conditions here? Do we know \$v_{in}\$ or \$v_{o}\$ or maybe some current value?

Comment: @Carl if all values are arbitrary, an equation would be acceptable. We're assuming an ideal op amp. In other words, it doesn't matter what the values are. I think the OP is just looking for an equation.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a thevenin equivalent of vin, 2R and the first R so that it looks like this:[image] Ux is the voltage divider output of R and 2R and Rx is the parallel combination of 2R and R.

$$U_x = v_{in}\cdot\frac{R}{R+2R}=v_{in}\cdot\frac{1}{3}$$

And for Rx
$$Rx = \frac{R\cdot 2R}{R+2R} = \frac{2R}{3}$$

So

$$R_{in} = Rx + R = \frac{5R}{3}$$

Finally

$$V_{out} = U_{x}\frac{R1}{R_{in}} = v_{in}\cdot\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{3}{5R}\cdot -R1=v_{in} = -\frac{R1}{5R}v_{in}$$

So you can say that $$R_{in} = 5R$$

Answer (score 0):

First, measure the Thevenin resistance.
[image]
Here, Thevenin resistance = (2R || R) + R = (5R/3)

Then, calculate the Thevenin voltage.
[image]

So,Thevenin voltage = (R/(R+2R)).Vin = Vin/3.

Now your circuit is reduced into:
[image]

Comment: The answer would be the same as @dinocroc123

Answer (score 0):

1) Assuming your question relates to Rin being the load seem by the left voltage source,

Rin will be 2.5 * R.

This answer requires an ideal opamp, with infinite gain, which forces the voltage to zero at (-) input of the opamp.

2) how to chose a value for Rin? very low values will get hot, and likely overload both the voltage source and the opamp (and the opamp power supply) but the random thermal KT noise will be low, which your system design may require.

For thinking purposes, I'd start with 1Kohm resistors, evaluating the heating and the random electron noise, then adjusting up or down from there.